# Getting "The connection was reset" on Centos 6 and 7 but not on Centos5

Tags: php, linux, apache, networking

Please excuse me if this has already been asked but I've been searching for a solution for days with no luck.

I have a PHP export script that has been working flawlessly on an old machine (CENTOS 5) for years. I just recently upgraded the server to CENTOS 6.8 and for some reason the script gets a connection reset. From the testing that I have done I see that the script is actually running on the server and its generating the export file just fine, however the process keeps repeating several times while the client sits there waiting for the process to finish and eventually getting a connection reset! I also noticed that if I run the export using a browser on the server itself, everything works find and the client alerts the user that the file is ready for download. The export btw regularly takes about 4-5 minutes and everything else on the very large website works normally.

I've checked all of my httpd.conf and php.ini files settings including matching all of the loaded modules with working CENTOS 5. I've also check my network settings thinking that there may be some reason why the client machine seems to not be receiving data from the server and therefore restarting the process. But everything checks out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Why would everything work fine on Centos5 but not on 6 and 7. Also, why does the script work on a browser used directly on the server vs. a browser on a client machine that keeps repeating.

I've also tested it with php 5.3 and 5.4 with the same results.

Please help!

Comment: OMG! Just had a coworker try it and he is using a PC vs. a Mac like me and his worked. I used both Firefox and Chrome on my Mac and he used Chrome on his PC. Did CENTOS 6 and 7 change something that effects Mac users?

Comment: You've certainly produced a lot of text describing the generalities of your problem without ever actually including pertinent code, configuration, error messages, or reproduction information.

Comment: Honestly I didn't know where to start. Maybe we can just jump to what made it work just now and what could be the issue. I am happy to provide any configuration settings. I just actually issued the following command #echo 8 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries to change the number of syn retries to 8 instead of 5 and now the mac clients work. This really goes beyond my knowledge about networking and how things may have changed between Centos 5 and 6 or 7.